# ¿Por qué me separa en P: y R: cuando utilizo el filtro de búsqueda "YII2"?

Tags: soporte, búsqueda

Cuando utilizo el buscador con la palabra "yii2", tanto en Stack Overflow en español como en inglés, me separa las preguntas con un prefijo de P: y R: que entiendo que son preguntas y respuesta. Pero eso no me sucede cuando filtro por la palabra "PHP".

No sé si se trata de alguna configuración que toqué accidentalmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para buscar/filtrar por etiqueta usa corchetes: `[yii2]`. En caso contrario buscará las publicaciones que contengan la palabra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En [Search is incorrectly adding tags to search criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47829/209901), esto es, *El buscador está añadiendo etiquetas a mis criterios de búsqueda de forma errónea*, Jeff Atwood explica:

> Las *n* principales etiquetas de la lista de etiquetas se convierten automáticamente en etiquetas cuando aparecen en búsquedas.
>
> Esto es así porque teníamos (y seguimos teniendo) un montón de usuarios a quien les encanta escribir cosas como "C#" en la caja de búsqueda.

Hice la prueba y parece que la *n* está definida en 80 para Stack Overflow en español:

- La 80.ª es [web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web). Si buscamos https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=web se convierte en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.
- La 81.ª es [entity-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework). Si buscamos https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=entity-framework no se convierte.

En tu caso, [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) es la 1.ª etiqueta en número de preguntas, por lo que https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php se convierte en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php. Sin embargo, [yii2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii2) apenas tiene 27 y está lejos de las 80 primeras ([web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web), la que marca esa posición, tiene 145), por lo que https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=yii2 no se convierte.

Comment: No sabía esto. Buena respuesta.