# ¿Hacemos [google+] sinónimo de [google-plus]?

Tags: discusión, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Tenemos

- [google+](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google%2b) con cuatro preguntas
- [google-plus](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-plus) también con cuatro preguntas

Considero que [google+](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google%2b) debería ser sinónimo de [google-plus](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-plus) pues el uso de `+` es problemático. Referencia [Error en la gestión de etiquetas activas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3089/65)

Si bien son pocas etiquetas y sería sencillo hacer la eliminación de una a mano, dado que el nombre oficial es `google+` sería útil tenerlo como sinónimo ¿No creen?

Comment: El bug que mencionas [se solucionó](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362816/1983854), Rubén

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias. Sin embargo al buscar `google+` en soes devuelve resultados con `google` pero no con `google+`. Otra cosa "rara", por ejemplo, al buscar `java` se reescribe la búsqueda a `[java]` pero no ocurre así con `google+`

Comment: Al buscar "google+" también a mí me da resultados muy variados, pero por ejemplo la [8.ª entrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/5952/83) sí contiene Google+. En cuanto a lo segundo, es un comportamiento esperado: _Las n principales etiquetas de la lista de etiquetas se convierten automáticamente en etiquetas cuando aparecen en búsquedas_. Hablé de ello en [¿Por qué me separa en P: y R: cuando utilizo el filtro de búsqueda “YII2”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2707/83)